# php file not outputting results

Tags: php, mysql

I have developed a script but whenever i open admin panel it shows just a blank page, however the same script works fine on my another server. I tried changing chmod of files and folders 644, 755, 775 and 777 but still it outputs a blank page.

The main script works fine but its only admin panel thats not working. I check .htaccess also same on both servers.

Any idea what is wrong?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the error log of your HTTP server (e.g. Apache).  In 99% of cases of a blank page, PHP has experienced a fatal error and exited before generating any output.

If this script works on another server, I'd check that the script can find everything it needs to `include` or `require`.  Files not found are common fatal errors when moving a script from one environment to another.  For instance, if you deployed the file to the new server without configuring the `include_path` correctly.

---

Re your comment about the notice you got:

> Notice: Undefined index: submit in /var/www/admin/index.php on line 8
>
> the function on line 8 is if($_POST['submit'] == 'Login')

This means your `$_POST` array does not contain a field `'submit'`.  Referencing a non-existant array index in PHP is an `E_NOTICE`.  You can fix this in the following way:

```
if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Login')
```

Comment: checked all files are present

Answer (score 2):

put this at the top of your admin page

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

The servers probably have different things installed which is causing an error that you can see.

Comment: sorry there was some silly mistake by me i tried again adding those lines and got this as my 1st error `Notice: Undefined index: submit in /var/www/admin/index.php on line 8`

Comment: the function on line 8 is `if($_POST['submit'] == 'Login')`

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid, but seeing as you all you said was it "outputs a blank page", are you sure there's no output at all? Have you checked the page source, just in case? Remember that if your page starts with a bad HTML tag or something similar, there will be output but that doesn't mean anything is actually rendered in the browser.

Also make sure output buffering isn't on... I can't remember if this can cause issues when trying to debug, but who knows?

Comment: theres no output `<html><head/><body/></html>` however when i echo before error line 8 as mentioned in comment of Galen i get echo outputted .